# copy and move xml node in the same xml based upon some matching values

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, vbscript

This is my first. I am not good at xml/xslt/c#/VBS programming. I searched on the site but could not find what I was looking for.

I need to find a match between `<pm-identifier>MGRTN0000004999999</pm-identifier>` inside structure `<deleted-assignment>` and that between `identifier>MGRTN0000004999999</pm-identifier>` inside structure `<product>` and if the values are equal, then node `<article-number>000000000004999995</article-number>` should be copied to structure `<deleted-assignment>` just beneath the line `<pm-identifier>MGRTN0000004999999</pm-identifier>`.

if there is no match, it should still show all nodes in the output. If there is a match, it should just copy over  from  to  as mentioned above.

There are multiple `<deleted-assignment>` with different values and multiple `<Product>` nodes.

```
<products>
    <deleted-assignment>
    <pm-identifier>MGRTN0000004999999</pm-identifier>
    <structure-system-identifier>Web Structure</structure-system-identifier>
    <structure-group-identifier>M010010080002</structure-group-identifier>
    <delete>true</delete>
    </deleted-assignment>
    <product>
    <pm-identifier>MGRTN0000004999999</pm-identifier>
    <prod-status>CREATED</prod-status>
    <val-status>Valid</val-status>
    <dup-status>Unique</dup-status>
    <con-status>New</con-status>
    <im-status>New</im-status>
    <wcs-status>New</wcs-status>
    <article-number>000000000004999995</article-number>
    <art-category>GA</art-category>
    <auto-order>No</auto-order>
    <archived>No</archived>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

I want my output like this:

```
<products>
    <deleted-assignment>
        <pm-identifier>MGRTN0000004999999</pm-identifier>
        <article-number>000000000004999995</article-number>
        <structure-system-identifier>Web Structure</structure-system-identifier>
        <structure-group-identifier>M010010080002</structure-group-identifier>
    <delete>true</delete>
    </deleted-assignment>
    <product>
            <pm-identifier>MGRTN0000004999999</pm-identifier>
        <prod-status>CREATED</prod-status>
        <val-status>Valid</val-status>
            <dup-status>Unique</dup-status>
        <con-status>New</con-status>
        <im-status>New</im-status>
        <wcs-status>New</wcs-status>
        <article-number>000000000004999995</article-number>
        <art-category>GA</art-category>
        <auto-order>No</auto-order>
        <archived>No</archived>
   </product>
</product>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your output sample entirely correct? In the input you have the `pm-indentifier` (under `deleted-identifier`) as "AMRTN0000004999999" but in the output it becomes "MGRTN0000004999999".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (!) I understand this correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="product" match="product" use="pm-identifier" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="deleted-assignment/pm-identifier">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('product', .)/article-number"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks but when I run this file in Altova, then I don't see <Article-Number> copied over to <deleted-assignments> I am doing the following things to run the test: assign xsl file to xml and then show the xml output.

Comment: @adit I am afraid I don't know how to help you with this. I have tested the above with your input - after correcting it to be well-formed by changing `</Product>` to `</product>` and `</Products>` to `</products>` - and it returns the expected result.

Comment: Michael, Sorry there was my mistake. Apologies for that. The code is working fine now. Thanks you so much